# Get parameters ajax and post into html

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I get parameters with Json like these:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetList(){
 var model = await db.CategoriesList.ToListAsync();
 return JSON(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
}
```

and I have view where I want to get some categories like these:

```
<div class="megamenu-content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img alt="150x190" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img alt="150x190" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img alt="150x190" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img alt="150x190" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img alt="150x190" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img alt="150x190" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is I don´t know much about Ajax, how can I call these categories to show in my view with AJAX?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a complete working example.Copy it in a new project -> run it -> understand how it works -> and then apply to your solution:

**Controller:**

```
public class Category
{
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string ImageSrc { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult HomePage()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetJsonData()
    {
        var c1 = new Category { CategoryName = "Dairy", ImageSrc = "http://gilowveld.sites.caxton.co.za/wp-content/uploads/sites/97/2016/03/Dairy-products.jpg" };
        var c2 = new Category { CategoryName = "Fruits", ImageSrc = "http://science-all.com/images/wallpapers/fruits-images/fruits-images-4.jpg" };

        List<Category> categories = new List<Category> { c1, c2 };

        return Json(categories, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "HomePage";
}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.getJSON("/Home/GetJsonData", null, function (data) {
            $("#result").empty();
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                var image = "<img style='height:100px;width:100px;' src='" + data[i].ImageSrc + "' />"

                var div = "<div><h1>" + data[i].CategoryName + "</h1>" + image + "</div>"
                $("#result").append(div);
            }
        });
    })
</script>
<div id="result">
</div>
```

**Output:**

[image: Fetching JSON data in ASP.NET MVC example]